# Extending JAMS Manufacturing logic gives message "Attempt by method to access 'PX.Data.PXGraphExtension`1<System.__Canon>..ctor()' failed

Tags: acumatica

Is there a limitation on extending JAMS Manufacturing logic?

I am trying to extend the Move page (AM302000).

Declaring the Graph extension (even without content) gives the message "Attempt by method 'JAMSCustomizations.MoveEntryExt..ctor()' to access method 'PX.Data.PXGraphExtension`1..ctor()' failed."

My graph extension is as simple as this:

```
namespace JAMSCustomizations
{
    public class MoveEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<JAMS.AM.MoveEntry>
    {
    }
}
```

I am working with these product versions:

Acumatica environment: 18.103.0022

Jams version: MFG - 18.107.0022.28 - 2018.07.02

**UPDATE**
To corroborate if it could be an instance error, in the same VS environment the AP Bills was extended successfully:

```
namespace JAMS.AM
{
    public class MoveEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
    {
        public PXSelect<APTran> Transactions;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would be interested to see if anyone else can recreate the issue as I tested 2 separate versions and instances and unable to recreate the issue. While the marked answer indicates what might have occurred, it doesn't point out that the structure of the inherited abstract graph as being a valid configuration to use. In a perfect world you can extend any other customization extension in the latest versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extending MoveEntry:
[image]

MoveEntry graph herits from MoveEntryBase base class:

```
class MoveEntry : MoveEntryBase<MoveEntry, AMBatch, Where<AMBatch.docType, Equal<AMDocType.move>>>
```

Unfortunately MoveEntryBase class constructor is protected instead of public so Acumatica framework can't call it:
[image]

In older versions of JAMS, MoveEntry class herited from PXGraph and had a public constructor:

```
class MoveEntry : PXGraph<MoveEntry, AMBatch>
```

[image]

Your code is fine to extend older versions of JAMS MoveEntry graph, for newer version I think you'll need to get binaries where MoveEntryBase constructor is public. The vendor (JAMS) will be able to assist you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response HB_ACUMATICA !

Comment: It appears that obfuscation inserts a protected constructor but the class being extended (MoveEntry) contains a public constructor.

Comment: With ILDASM DLL version 17.207.0029.29 is showing a protected constructor. It is indeed an implicit constructor. It appears to be inline with the error message but I haven't tested it.

Comment: By old version this would be a 6.1 version which i don't think is an option. The error should not be received. The structure for MoveEntry to MoveEntryBase to PXGraph is no different (while not common) found in Acumatica examples in use.

Answer (score 0):

No limitation as the JAMS move entry is just another PXGraph. No different than using a standard Acumatica PXGraph shipped with the product. While MoveEntry inherits from a base abstract class MoveEntry has a public constructor and the base class inherits from PXGraph. Using the MoveEntry graph as an extension should function the same. Acumatica has similar examples such as ReclassifyTransactionsBase with a Projected constructor and any graph extension extended from a graph which inherits ReclassifyTransactionsBase should work (assuming the inheriting graph has a public constructor).

Maybe something is not loaded correctly in your environment? Are you trying to build the site with your solution? Try to turn that off is so.

I tested the versions you have posted and publishing a code file or using a visual studio solution resulted in zero errors with the following code sample:

```
using System;
using PX.Data;
using JAMS.AM;

namespace JAMSCustomizations
{
    public class MoveEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<MoveEntry>
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName<AMBatch.tranDesc>(Base.batch.Cache, "CAN YOU SEE ME");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screen shot showing my published sample working from an Acumatica code file:

[image]

Sample from a visual studio project yields the same working result:

[image]

You can try a similar non JAMS graph for an alternative test:

```
// public abstract class ReclassifyTransactionsBase<TGraph> : PXGraph<TGraph> where TGraph : PXGraph
// Contains a protected constructor
public class ReclassifyTransactionsProcessorExt : PX.Data.PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.GL.Reclassification.Processing.ReclassifyTransactionsProcessor>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }
}
```

I tested using the same version of JAMS (18.107.0022.28) and with Acumatica versions 18.103.0022 & 18.104.0023.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Brendan. When I extend the logic from the Customization project editor, the result is successful (like yours). However, when I do it from Visual Studio, the error is shown. I will verify if it's something in my VS environment. Thanks again

Comment: Quick follow up. Would you know why the source graph logic is not visible like in other Acumatica pages? I am looking to modify the datamember from the Move's page grid in order to show additional information from the OperNbr. In this case, I can infer the definition of that datamember based in the key fields of the table in SQL, but in either case, being able to see the source graph could be useful for more complicated customizations.

Comment: You can use any decompile tool to see the graph source code if that is what you are asking? Do you have a reference in your solution to JAMS.dll?

Comment: In some versions of JAMS MoveEntry is just another PXGraph "class MoveEntry : PXGraph<MoveEntry, AMBatch>". In others not quite: "MoveEntry : MoveEntryBase<MoveEntry, AMBatch, Where<AMBatch.docType, Equal<AMDocType.move>>>"

Comment: My guess is that the issue happens because MoveEntryBase constructor is not public.

Comment: @Brendan I took your comment as a tacit agreement to go ahead and reverse-engineer the binaries so posted an answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I will use a previous version of the JAMS product for this customization.

Comment: This logic was added in 2017R2 so you would have to be on a 6.1 version which i am sure would not work

Comment: The version should matter. I tested a few different versions of 2018R1 and guessing the issue you have is with the environment. Going to a different version should not make a difference. Similar examples of SomeGraph : SomeBaseGraph : PXGraph exist in Acumatica and should all function the same.

Comment: @Brendan, I tried to extend the AP Bills page in the same environment to review if the error is presented there as well, but in that case it worked correctly. I will modify my Question to include the AP extension (basically, I just simplified the grid datamember to list all transactions regardless of the Bill). In your tests, did you always use the Customization Project editor or did you try it from VS as well? Thanks for your help.

Comment: i did both - using VS and customization project editor. When do you receive the error? trying to compile? opening the page? publishing? I used a similar example using an Acumatica example to exclude JAMS from the equation and works the same.

Comment: Yes. As the page it's refreshed, then the error is shown. We do not get to see the page

Comment: Have you reset your site to confirm there is nothing lingering that could cause an issue? I could send you customization project i used if you want to confirm

Comment: @Brendan I reset the IIS and the server. The error persisted. However, in this particular case I will manage it directly in the App_RunTimeCode folder which will allow me to code it from VS. Thanks for the great feedback!

Comment: Is this a developer instance? have you changed any settings in the web.config? The instances I tested on were clean non developer instances with the demo data and the customizations published for the first time.

Comment: @Brendan it is a newly created Acumatica instance with the SalesDemo demo data. I published the JAMS package and then I proceeded to extend the Graph in VS. The web.Config has not been modified

Comment: strange. What runs in app runtime code would be the same that runs from a dll as it relates to a graph extension. Why one way would work and another way not work on your environment is strange.

Comment: @Brendan I agree